# Why does hugepages prefer permanent swap, and how much should it have?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, swap

I'm using hugepages on an Ubuntu 16.04.3 system and when I run

`#  hugeadm --explain`

the last line says:

`Note: Permanent swap space should be preferred when dynamic huge page pools are used.`

Using Google, I'm not coming up with a good reason *why*.   I'm also not sure what size swap would be a good size for the huge pages in this scenario.  [ I've been running this way without swap for several years, but I'm always looking for ways to make the systems better, and if swap is "preferred" then I'll add it, I just wanted to grock the reasoning and size it appropriately. ]

Comment: I wonder if by "permanent swap space" they mean using a swap partition instead of a swap file.  That would make sense - a swap file may be fragmented, so swapping out a single huge page may require writing all over the disk, which would be bad for performance.

Comment: I don't have either configured on my Linux system as setting up an explicit swap area is not a standard practice for most modern Linux deployments.